# How can npm know how to update `package.json` after run `npm install xx`, `npm uninstall xx`

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-scripts

I am very curious about it , but don't know how can it know where  to insert or delete package name  ?

Comment: You can always read the source code on https://github.com/npm/cli and clarify what you want to know.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to auto insert latest version in package.json

> npm install --save xx

Comment: Since `npm@5.0.0` running `npm install <name>` (without the `--save` flag) by default adds the package to the `dependencies` section of _package.json_ -  unless `npm config set save false` has been set of course. The [docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install) no longer include the `--save` flag as it's redundant. However, the `--save` flag is available when running [`npm uninstall <name>`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/uninstall) if you want to remove from _package.json_.